# Curious about the text when booting

Tags: 13.10

So whenever I boot up Ubuntu or shut it down, it displays the whole process on black screen with white text, instead of showing only the loading screen of ubuntu.  Why is that?  It does not look really good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the text boot, you can do that. Here's how:

1. Open a terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file type:

   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   this should open the file. Look for the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and change its value to `"quiet splash"` so that the line would look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save the edits, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor,
3. Now, run this command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux distros will display the boot loading process and the shutdown process in a command-line style. This happens before the window manager has loaded, and after it has closed down. It's normal, though not always pretty. I've never investigated if there are any methods to make those processes "quiet". In some cases, it can be handy if something goes awry during those processes, as it is a command shell of sorts and you might be able to recover from an error though it, or see what process is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

quick tip if you add loglevel=0 after quiet and before splash like this `"quiet loglevel=0 splash"` in your `/etc/default/grub` file it will make your boot even quieter also if you ever want to remove the echoed loading Linux and loading initial ramdisk you can edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and remove the echoed lines in the config